# Trekking in Leh / Ladakh, India in January

Tags: india, trekking

I am planning a trip to India in January and would like to organise a 8-day trek in Leh/Ladakh. I have come across the well-advertised frozen chadar trek, but it is too long for what I have in mind (usually more than 11 days). What other treks can be done in winter?
It seems that simply flying to Leh and booking one of the available group treks is very easy in the summer. Is it also possible in January? What would be a reliable source to find agencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this trip by Make my trip](https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/9285-chadar_trek_frozen_river_trek_on_zanskar.html)? The trip is only 8 days in total. I have done a trip with them in the past, and they are one of the main tour operators in the country.

Comment: MakeMyTrip is an online travel agent, not a tour operator.

Comment: It is, but it also offers holiday packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tracking the snow leopard in the Hemis National Park. The trek itself would be for 5-6 days. It would still be difficult to spot a cat. But the trek is usually done in winters since the snow-leopard comes down during that time. Usually, since Ladakh is visited during the summer, you won't have many group departures in winter and it may be difficult to find one.